# Saving forms and redirecting to a new URL in Django

Tags: python, django, database, forms

I'm creating a project with django and am having trouble with some of the basics, my aim is to have a homepage with a search box. When a search term is entered, the server gathers data from various api's, saves the data to the database then directs the user to a results page which displays this data.

So far I have managed to create a page that takes the search term and saves the data to the database. However if I try to then redirect to a new page it breaks, specifically the data doesn't save to the database. I'm having real trouble finding information on what to do next.

I have a model:

```
class film(models.Model):
    filmName = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=120)
    quotient = models.FloatField()
    rating = models.FloatField()
    gross = models.IntegerField()
    star = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    releaseDate = models.DateField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.filmName
```

With a form:

```
class searchFilm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = film
        fields = ['filmName']
```

A two view methods:

```
def home(request):
    title = "Culturnomicon"
    form = searchFilm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        searchedFilm = form.save(commit = False)

        fixedName = searchedFilm.filmName.replace(' ', '+')

        url = 'http://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=APIKEY&query='+fixedName

        urlRequest = Request(url)

        try:
            reponse = urlopen(urlRequest)
            filmData = reponse.read()
            parsed_json = json.loads(filmData)
        except URLError, e:
            print "didnt work"

        firstResult = parsed_json['results'][0]

        filmId = str(firstResult['id'])

        filmData = getFilmData(filmId)



        if parsed_json['total_results'] != 0:
            searchedFilm = saveFilm(searchedFilm, filmData)
            searchedFilm.save()


    context = {
    "template_title": title,
    "form": form,
    }




    return render(request, "home.html", context)

def results(request):

    return render(request, "results.html", {})
```

and a template:

```
        <form method="POST" action="{% url 'results' %}">
            {{form}}
            {% csrf_token %}
            <input type="submit" value ="Search" class = 'btn'/>
        </form>
```

Any advice on what to do next would be greatly appreciated.

I also have the feeling that having methods to gather the API information may be a bad idea, is it bad to do this and if so how can I fix it?

Comment: What does "it breaks" entail? errors? Also, printing "didnt work" isn't a very good way of handling an exception..

Comment: If I do action="{% url 'results' %}" in the template rather than action="" it redirects to a new page but none of the data is saved

Comment: Well yes it would because you're calling a different view that just renders a page

Answer (score 0):

If all you really want to do is load a different template then you don't need to have a separate view, you just move the `return render(..."results.html"` inside of the `if form.is_valid()` statement after you've done all you need with the database.

You may need to extend the render call to include some context data about what results that template should actually display however.

If you do want a separate view, then you need to move the handling of the form to the other view.

```
def home(request):
    title = "Culturnomicon"
    form = searchFilm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        # Your logic
        return render(request, "results.html", {})

    context = {
    "template_title": title,
    "form": form,
    }

    return render(request, "home.html", context)
```

Comment: shouldn't you always redirect in a `form.is_valid()` scenario?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I'm very new to web development and django, so sorry if this is basic. Could you go into a bit more detail on how this would be done?

Comment: @thebjorn - Perhaps, it depends on your requirements. (There are reasons why you should which I'm ignoring to keep my answer simple)

Comment: Thanks, I've moved the form logic to results(request): so now the search saves the data and directs to the results page, however I still have a problem, in results.html I have some place holder text
<p>Place holder text</p>
However when it goes to the results page it's just blank.

Comment: @user2320239 - "You may need to extend the render call to include some context data about what results that template should actually display however."

Comment: Thanks, yeah think I understand that, however not even the content hard coded into results.html are being displayed.

Comment: @user2320239 - If you have another question then you should ask it as a new question, if this answer solved *this* problem, then you should consider accepting it.